# Fast blacklist processor in php?

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace

I have a website with a search function, but i want to check the search terms for blacklisted keywords

Problem is the list has got too big and now the site loads slow (3-5s first byte) with a high CPU load.
The list has 45.000 lines in it (~1.5 mb)

I have tried to split in several smaller files but its still slow

The blacklist function works for every search
You can see it below

```
function CheckForBlockedWords(){

     $blackList=array();
 $string1 = trim(strtolower(str_replace("_"," ",$_GET['search'])));
 $string1 = preg_replace('/-+/', ' ',$string1);
 $string1 = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$string1);
 $string1 = trim($string1);
  foreach (glob("/home/keywords2/*") as $file) {
        $blackList = file($file);

foreach($blackList as $word)
            {

                 $string2 = trim(strtolower(str_replace("_"," ",$word)));
                 $string2 = str_replace("-"," ",$string2);

                 //$string2 = preg_replace('/-+/', ' ',$string2);


                 $string2 = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$string2);


                $string2 = trim($string2);

                if(strpos($string1, $string2) !== false   )
                {
                    echo "<div class='blockedSearch'>What you are searching is blocked!</div>";
                    return true;
                }
            }

 }

        return false;
}
```

any way to do this faster ?

Comment: This question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Filesystem is slow. Database are fast because they have indexes and can cache queries. So you'd better setup a small table and search in that table if the keywords typed by the user are listed there. This is so much faster then reading files from your disk, and looping all over them.

Comment: RAM is fast.  You could use memcache, redis, apc, or some type of apache solr search.  All use memory and are faster than a database.

Comment: If your database server is configured properly then it will have comparable speed to using an DIY solution with memcache etc. The latter will take lot's more time to configure, is hard on shared servers, does not work when php is running as cgi, and requires lots of experience. Jup RAM is faster, but development is significantly slower :-)

Comment: i have tried with APC , and it was even slower.. i would like to use another solution other than DB's, on my previous work it slowed down the site i have used it. i will try the sql and see how that turns out , i have no experience with memcache , but i think that will run faster.